# Unable to open Preferences windows on scilab

Tags: scilab

I'm willing to increase the size of my fonts in `scilab 6.1.0`, but either with the menu or the command `preferences()`, the *Preferences* window doesn't appear.

No message, nowhere, explain what have happened. I see no menu entry to find logs files outputs, in case *Scilab* stumbled on an exception.
And I don't know, on *Debian 11* where I am using it, where its log folder is, if it has some.

I am a beginner with scilab. It's the first time I'm using it...

What's the trick to make that preferences windows appearing?

Comment: Are you using the official build (provided as a .tar.gz file @ https://gitlab.com/scilab/scilab/-/releases) or the Debian (unstable) package ? Nevertheless, if you launched Sciab from the command line you will see (java, likely) messages in the terminal.

Comment: I did a `sudo apt-get install scilab` on Debian 11, if I remember well. I didn't expect it to be bundled with an unstable version. Usually, when this happens, in the following months a `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` offers to install a corrected software. It's not the case, here.

Comment: Since 6.1 version scilab package in Debian or Ubuntu has always been unstable (even if bundled with stable dists) because of the aggressive versioning policy of dependencies packages... Please open a *new* issue on https://gitlab.com/scilab/scilab/-/issues (the issue where you crossposted was windows-specific) and give the messages you see on the command line.

Comment: Marc, which font do you will to change: the desktop one (menus, etc) ; the console one ; the Scinotes one (code editor)?

Answer (score 0):

Without the preferences interface, as a workaround, you can change the preferences settings directly in the SCIHOME/XConfiguration.xml file, where SCIHOME is the path returned in the console when you type `SCIHOME` and validate.

Then edit the XConfiguration.xml with you preferred code editor (Notepad++ is definitely my favorite on Windows).

In XConfiguration.xml, find the `<fonts ..>..</fonts>` section. It looks like this:

```
  <fonts title="_(Fonts)">
    <body>
      <fonts font-face="plain" font-name="Monospaced" font-size="13" item="Console" latex="15" system="true">
        <item desktop="false" font-face="plain" font-name="Monospaced" font-size="12" name="Console" xconf-uid="console-font"/>
        <item desktop="false" font-face="plain" font-name="Monospaced" font-size="12" name="Scinotes" xconf-uid="scinotes-font"/>
        <!-- ... lines in comments-->
      </fonts>
    </body>
  </fonts>
```

In the interface, corresponding entries look like this:
[image]

For instance, to set the Console's font in a custom way, the `item` with `name="Console"` must have the attribute `desktop="false"` (to not be driven by the Desktop font), and then the `font-size="THE NUMBER YOU WANT"`

Then save the file. Finally, close and restart Scilab to take the change (done in this way) into account.

Comment: Thanks! This workaround helped me. But some aren't working: I've uncommented and sat : `<item name="Help" desktop="false" font-name="Monospaced" font-face="plain" font-size="16"/>` but an `help exp` still shows me a page with a font, that in this case, has its descriptions (like "_exp(X) is the (element-wise) exponential of the entries of X._") coming with a font lower than 10 points. Maybe 8.

Comment: The lines are commented likely because they do not work ;-) More simply, to tune the font size of help pages, just open a page : help exp ; then CTRL+mouse wheel to change the font size ; and that's it: the same font will be used for any next help call for the current or any forthcoming scilab session.

Answer (score 0):

You will find a solution to run Scilab successfully at the end of this message but please read the whole answer.

I installed a brand new Debian 11 virtual machine to see the actual error message:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:50: White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
FATAL ERROR:  'The xsl:import element children must precede all other element children of an xsl:stylesheet element, including any xsl:include element children.'
           :The xsl:import element children must precede all other element children of an xsl:stylesheet element, including any xsl:include element children.
Could not load file: /usr/share/scilab//modules/preferences/src/xslt/XConfiguration.xsl
...
    at org.scilab.modules.preferences.XCommonManager.generateViewDOM(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.preferences.XCommonManager.refreshDisplay(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.preferences.XConfigManager.displayAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at org.scilab.modules.preferences.
```

I checked that the `XConfiguration.xsl` file is the same in upstream, this is actually the case. I think you should do two things:

1. Report the problem to Debian.
2. Download the Scilab team tar.gz distribution of Scilab at [the releases page](https://gitlab.com/scilab/scilab/-/releases) then extract the archive in your home directory (the main folder will be named `scilab-6.1.1`).
   You will have to install a complimentary package (needed for Debian 11) to run Scilab:

```
sudo apt-get install libtinfo5
```

Then launch scilab like this (on the command line):

```
scilab-6.1.1/bin/scilab &
```

You will see that Scilab runs smoothly and that the Preferences pane works.

Comment: I don't know what I should really write to Debian (and how). Wouldn't it be easier, for everyone, that _Scilab_ sends a 6.1.1 release version to their update process? How does other software that are updated by `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` do? We can guess that most Linux version of Scilab encounter the same problem?

Comment: OSS software does not work like this. This is the responsablity of Linux distributions to package software not the one of the upstream project. This is the same for ALL OSS projects. Like I already said recent Linux distributions upgrade libraries at their (fast) own pace which creates problems to software having bigger time constants. Debian adds its own patches and recompile software to distribute them as readily installable packages. Long time users of Scilab under Linux are quite conservative as they don't upgrade their Linux each time a new version is released...

Comment: So, just test the solution I gave you (install the tar.gz official version + the complimentary package) and validate the answer if this works for you. I will report the problem to Debian guys.